# View ID on Measurement Protocol - Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I am going trough the documentation of Google Analytics, but the documentation doesn't seem to mention when the user wants to send the hit to a specific view. It does require the property ID but any signal of the View ID..

I have also searched on the internet but I cannot find anything. It is pretty rare that there is no documentation on this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You don't see it because all views receive the data. You send the data to the property. You need to filter out the traffic in the view configurations, not at collection time.